# traditional window popup vs inbuilt poup

Tags: web-app, modal-dialog, popup

Almost all of the websites/apps uses the custom built popup (HTML) to show menu,messages,page load etc... but, some of the apps still insist on opening the same in a browser based popup window (which is annoying ofcourse).

I know both has advantage and disadvantage to each other.

So, my question is, what is the best popup method? what would be the UI experience on each of them. which one will you vote up?

(OK firefox window may not be good e.g to show but its to give an idea of traditional window :) )

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sree - this isn't really an answerable question. It falls into the catagory discussed in the [FAQ] around what not to ask because basically ["every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @JonW i want to know the difference in usage of the both, how can it be not constructive?, clearly i am looking forward for User experience with different type of popup box...

Comment: Because you haven't stated a particular usage, just 'what is best'. If you can provide a situation for use and ask which type of popup is appropriate *for a specific situation* then that would be a constructive question and we can re-open the question for you. Do you have a particular usage in mind?

Comment: @JonW no i do not have situation but , i want to know under what situation the above two popup can be used, and why still traditional popup is used in some websites and reason for it..

Comment: in that case it's still not a constructive question because every answer is a valid one. Someone could say "the browser popup is useful for help text" and someone else could say "the browser popup is useful for terms and conditions" and both are equally valid. You need to give a specific use case to this question to be able to get useful answers.

Comment: @JonW ok i will try to reframe the question if i can get some usecase. tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

While sometime business logic and technical limitations might dictate which type you need to use, I would have to say whenever possible modal dialogs are the best. They are simply easier to control, style, and are not affected by those nasty popup blockers every browser seems to install.

Answer (score 0):

### System alerts

People are used to `alert();` windows as **Alarm**. So if you're using them, then *just to interrupt* the user completely.

Be aware that users will normally abort or confirm, as they just want to say

> Yes, I don't want to have that f***cking alert!

### Dialogs

Modal »pop-up« are a way to give out information or choices. That's why they're also called *dialogs*. They are actually *talking* to the people.

### Fly-outs

What you've shown ↑ from the SE network is *imho* a "fly-out" **menu** and *not* a »pop-up«. Use it to give the user an *additional*, small, quick overview & access menu for highly complex separate functions (like the messaging systems).